# How to install monitoring agent on GCP Compute VM that is set to a Service Account?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I have a GCP VM set to use a service account so in the VM instance details on the console:

> **Service account**
>
> blarg@MYPROJECT.iam.gserviceaccount.com

When I run the command for installing the monitoring agent I saw this:

> Updating project ssh metadata...failed.
> Updating instance ssh metadata...failed.
> **ERROR**: (gcloud.beta.compute.ssh) Could not add SSH key to instance metadata:
>
> - Required 'compute.instances.setMetadata' permission for 'projects/MYPROJECT/zones/us-central1-a/instances/MYVM'

I gave the service account the *Compute Admin* role on the *instance* (not the whole project) and re-ran. The results are then more confusing:

> Updating project ssh metadata...failed.
> Updating instance ssh metadata...failed.
> **ERROR**: (gcloud.beta.compute.ssh) Could not add SSH key to instance metadata:
>
> - The user does not have access to service account > 'blarg@MYPROJECT.iam.gserviceaccount.com'.  User: 'blarg@MYPROJECT.iam.gserviceaccount.com'.  Ask a project owner to grant you the iam.serviceAccountUser role on the service account

Do I really grant the `iam.serviceAccountUser` role *on* the service account so it can use itself? Is there another way I can run the script *as me* rather than the service account since I am a project admin/owner?

Comment: You can run the script as _you_ once you are authenticated using `gcloud auth login` then selecting _you_ in the auth screen. By the way when you run `gcloud auth list` is blarg@MYPROJECT.iam.gserviceaccount.com account the one selected ?

Comment: If you are creating a resource (VM) that itself will use a service account, you must have the permission **iam.serviceAccountUser** to deploy that service. It does not matter that the service account is the same and the one referenced by the resource.

Comment: @MBHAPhoenix - Yes, blarg@MYPROJECT.iam.gserviceaccount.com is shown as selected when running `gcloud auth list`. Thanks for the command hints

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's correct, per the official documentation of the compute admin role:

> Full control of all Compute Engine resources.
>
> If the user will be managing virtual machine instances that are
> configured to run as a service account, you must also grant the
> roles/iam.serviceAccountUser role.

Link: https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/access/iam